# 2D integrals in SciPy

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, scipy, wolfram-mathematica, numerical-integration

I am trying to integrate a multivariable function in [SciPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciPy) over a 2D area.
What would be the equivalent of the following [Mathematica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematica) code?

```
In[1]:= F[x_, y_] := Cos[x] + Cos[y] 

In[2]:= Integrate[F[x, y], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {y, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]

Out[2]= 0
```

Looking at the [SciPy documentation](http://www.scipy.org/SciPyPackages/Integrate) I could only find support for one-dimensional quadrature. Is there a way to do multidimensional integrals in SciPy?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think it would work something like this:

```
def func(x,y):
    return cos(x) + cos(y)

def func2(y, a, b):
    return integrate.quad(func, a, b, args=(y,))[0]

print integrate.quad(func2, -pi/2, pi/2, args=(-pi/2, pi/2))[0]
```

[Wolfram|Alpha agrees](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+cos%28x%29%2Bcos%28y%29+dxdy%2C+x%3D-pi%2F2..pi%2F2%2C+y%3D-pi%2F2..pi%2F2)

edit:  I just discovered [dblquad](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.dblquad.html#scipy.integrate.dblquad) which seems to do exactly what you want:

```
print integrate.dblquad(func, -pi/2, pi/2, lambda x:-pi/2, lambda x:pi/2)[0]
```

Comment: This works.  However, I will be integrating the function over hundreds of thousands of small cells. Wouldn't this be too slow as it would involve calling a python function?

Comment: I don't know if integrate.quad will internally vectorize the function or not.  I know integrate.quadrature does, but I got an error when I tried it on a double integral.  You could always make the integration faster by increasing the tolerance.  Or better yet, find an exact solution!

Answer (score 9):

If you want to do symbolic integration, have a look at sympy ([code.google.com/p/sympy](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/)):

```
import sympy as s
x, y = s.symbols('x, y')
expr = s.cos(x) + s.sin(y)
expr.integrate((x, -s.pi, s.pi), (y, -s.pi, s.pi))
```

Comment: There must be a space between x and y in 'xy'.